# ERROR en Jupyter con operadores de decisión

Tags: python, jupyter

Me pasa algo bien extraño, que al poner el siguiente código con Jupyter:

```
x=int(input("Escribe un número: "))
if x>0 and x<10:
    print("Has escrito un número en el rango de [0,10]")
```

Me sucede lo mismo al poner `and` y `or`

Mil gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## ¿Problema?

Lo que tienes no es un error, simplemente es el resultado de los *operadores lógicos* que haz aplicado (`and`, `or`) para eso nos podemos guiar de una tabla de verdad.

[image: tabla_de_verdad]

En la proposición *"y"* (`^`) se nos dice que será verdad cuando ambos valores sean verdadero, mientras que en la proposición *"o"* (`v`) se dice que se cumplirá cuando uno de sus valores sea verdad.

Pasando eso a *programación* existe los valores *falsy* y *truthy* los cuales existen para definir una variable como boleano o *boolean*, como ejemplo rápido.
Se evalúa como `False`:

- `None`
- `False`
- `0` (sea un entero o un número flotante)
- Colecciones vacías (cadenas, tuplas, listas y diccionarios)

Se evalúa como `True`

- El resto de los objetos, es decir cualquier objeto no vacío y `True`

## Tu *"problema"*

Como dije no es un problema en si ya que lo que pasa es que no has sabido utilizar una expresión correcta, veamos a detalle lo que significa y pasa con cada una de las expresiones y operadores.

Primero hay que recordar que las expresiones se evalúan de izquierda a derecha, dicho esto vamos a ver lo que pasa.

### **and**

El `and` evaluara si ambas condiciones se cumple, es tal caso retorna `True`, si la primera condicion es evaluada como `False`, ya no se evaluara la segunda. Para tu ejemplo se valida lo siguiente:

> Si `x` es mayor que `0` **Y** si `x` es menor que `10` devuelve `True`, por lo que todo numero en el rango de 1 a 9 devolverá **True**

### **or**

Con el `or` se evalúa si solo uno de las expresiones o valores es `True`, con que **uno** de las condiciones sea `True` devolverá `True`, para el ejemplo se valida lo siguiente:

> Si `x` es mayor que `0` devuelve `True` o si `x` es menor que `10` devuelve `True`. Esto ya que solo hace falta que una de estas dos se cumpla para que retorne `True`.

Existe algo llamado *"evaluación de cortocircuito"*, esto quiere decir que solo se evalúa las expresiones necesarias, por ejemplo en el caso del `and`:

> Si `x>0` retorna `False` ya no se evalúa `x<10` ya que es necesario que ambos sean `True` o `False`, si se niega la expresión

## Solución

Si lo que quieres es validar que el numero ingresado se encuentra en un rango, puedes usar la función `range(inicio,fin)`

```py
x=int(input("Escribe un número: "))
if x in range(0,11):#se pone 11 para que cuente el 10, acepta numeros del 1 al 10
    print("Has escrito un número en el rango de [0,10]")

#o simplemente usar esta expresion 0<x<10
```

Si algo no te quedo claro avísame y tratare de explicarlo.

Comment: todo me quedó claro, gracias!!!